# How to access HTML elements in a nested fashion using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to access HTML elements in a nested fashion through Selenium and Python.

For example I have:

```
box = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
```

which represents the body of the data I'd like to mine. I'd like to iterate through each row in this body (each row characterized by a `<tr>` tag) using something like:

```
for driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tr') in box:
```

But obviously that's not possible because box is a Selenium object and is non-iterable.

What's the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

An optimum approach would be to construct [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) which would traverse from the parent till the descendants as follows:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody tr"):
      print(element.text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr"):
      print(element.text)
  ```

Comment: Awesome, appreciate the advice!

Comment: Just one more quick question, and I'll be a little more specific this time: I need to access elements `td` in a row `tr` in a body `tbody`. Your method iterates through each element but has no way of distinguishing which row it came from. I need to do something like:   `for each row in body, create new array, for each element in row, add element to array`. And unless I'm not properly understanding your solution, I don't think that's possible with the code you provided. How would I distinguish which elements are part of which row, so I could add them to the appropriate array.

Comment: @MatthewKaplan I'm afraid. Sounds like a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.